# Firebase deploy only functions process

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

If I have two Firebase functions (`fire1` and `fire2`) that share a helper function (`doSum`), will deploying with `firebase deploy --only functions:fire1` change the environment of `fire2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, each function is fully indepndent of each other.  Each deployed function gets its own copy of the entire deployed project.  A deploy of a single function will not in any way affect the code deployed for any other function.

Comment: Awesome! Might I suggest having this in the docs?

Thank you.