# How to deploy firebase cloud function dependencies require js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using node.js to deploy firebase cloud function, I got a problem I have some js files require my custom functions. When my custom function is updated, how can I deploy it?
For instance, I have two js files Purchase.js and MyTime.js

**Puchase.js**
const MyTime = require('../Scoz/MyTime.js');

**MyTime.js**
some methods

If I only modified MyTime.js how can I deploy it?
Normally, I use firebase deploy --only functions: Purchase to deploy function, but if I only want to update "MyTime.js". How can I do?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just update those custom function (which are not cloud functions). You would have to deploy the function(s) which uses that custom functions.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:cloudFunctionOne
```

This will deploy only `cloudFunctionOne` and if I recall correctly, the custom function will be updated for this cloud function only.

Comment: Thank you very much.

"the custom function will be updated for this cloud function only" <= does this mean every cloud function which requires my custom function(MyTime.js) need to be redeployed again.

Comment: @Scozirge2 I guess yes. Checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360833/firebase-deploy-only-functions-process) for confirmation on that. If there's no issue you can deploy all functions at once tbh.